# To find a if value is present in between and check a specific value is present at the end in DAX+Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Have data like below:

[image]

|id|Created|Timespent|State|Index| are the column names

How to find id's which have state P1 or P2 in between and id's which have state ending at P3 or P4 in DAX?

The result should show id's which have P1 or P2 in between and the last value that is at max(created) the state should be P3 or P4, in this case both id's

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Update your question and paste the table as a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). What do you mean by "have P1 or P2 in between"? Do mean, get all ids that are in latest P3 or P4 state *and* where previously in P1 or P2 state. Finally, what do you want to do with this? Filter on these ids?

Comment: yes, to filter on these id's

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Measure based on `SUMX` on the distinct values of IDs, then for each do the checks...

```
Special count = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(Ticket[id]),
    (
      var lastRow = CALCULATETABLE( TOPN(1, Ticket, [Created], DESC) )
      var isLastStateP3P4 = MINX(lastRow, [State]) IN { "P3", "P4" }
      var hasP1P2 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Ticket), Ticket[State] IN { "P1", "P2" }) > 0
      return IF( isLastStateP3P4 && hasP1P2, 1)
    )
  )
```